# Existing way to Java map Optional<> onto object instead of to another object?

Tags: java, option-type

I'm familiar with `Optional.map(mapper)`, which maps an optional object to something else. So if I wanted to do something with an optional `Foo` and a non-optional `Bar`, I could do:

```
Optional<Foo> foobar = foo.map(foo -> foo.addBar(bar))
```

This works sort of like:

```
Optional<Foo> foobar = foo.isPresent() ? Optional.of(foo.get().add(bar)) : Optional.empty();
```

But I'm seeing a recurring pattern in which *`bar`* is optional. The functionality I want to replicate looks something like this:

```
Foo foobar = bar.isPresent() ? foo.add(bar.get()) : foo;
```

In other words, if the *other* thing is present, let me do something with it in regards to my existing thing; otherwise, just give me my existing thing back.

I could imagine making my own `Optionals.doIfOtherPresent(T object, Optional<U> optional, BiFunction<? super T, ? super U, ? extends T> fn)`. I would use it like this:

```
Foo foobar = doIfOtherPresent(foo, bar, foo::add);
```

Is there something in the Java library that does this already?

Comment: `optionalBar.map(bar -> foo.add(bar)).orElse(foo)`?

Answer (score 1):

Using `bar` rather than `foo` seems to simplify it:

```
Foo foobar = bar
         .map(b -> foo.map(f -> f.add(b)))
         .orElse(foo)
         .orElse(null); // if foo is not present
```

`bar.map(b -> foo.map(f -> f.add(b)))` returns `Optional<Optional<Foo>>` that is "present" if `bar` is present.

`.orElse(foo)` reverts to the original `Optional<Foo>` if `bar` was not present (or returns `foo.map(f -> f.add(b))` otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

Given the example you've provided, it seems that you want to apply the operation `foo.add` if `bar` is present otherwise return `foo`:

```
Foo foobar = bar.isPresent() ? foo.add(bar.get()) : foo;
```

Thus, I'd say it's so short that it's not worthy of creating a utility method for it.

```
Foo foobar = optBar.map(f::add).orElse(f); // map to Foo if bar is present else return `f`
```

- if `optBar` has a present state, we apply the `map` operation and `orElse` returns that mapped value.
- if `optBar` has an absent state, the `orElse` method returns the supplied default value `f`.

---

Another thing, are you getting the result as an `Optional<Bar>` in the first place or are you manually wrapping `Bar` into an Optional? if it's the latter I'd probably just use a simple `if` statement which would be the ideal solution, i.e.

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
if(bar != null) foo = foo.add(bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the other answers taking a starting point from an `Optional<Bar>` are great for many situations. If you need `foo.addBar` conditionally in a longer method chain involving a `Foo` at some stage, the approach can be fit in there too (not tested yet):

```
    Optional<Foo> foobar = foo.map(foo -> bar.map(bar -> foo.addBar(bar)));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `Optional.flatMap()`.

The following construct:

`Foo result = optionalBar.isPresent() ? optionalFooFromBar( optionalBar.get() ) : foo;`

Can be rewritten as:

`Foo result = optionalBar.flatMap( bar -> optionalFooFromBar( bar ) ).orElse( foo );`

Note that you save a whole two characters.